# Cosmological triangle with PLANCK results

Tags: cosmology, experimental-physics, dark-energy, cosmic-microwave-background, cosmological-constant

Is there an updated version of the cosmological triangle with recent PLANCK results included?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[Here is an excellent (blog) summary of the results](http://scienceblogs.com/startswithabang/2013/03/21/what-the-entire-universe-is-made-of-thanks-to-planck/).  The most relevant figure being:

[image]

[Here is the full index of the Planck release papers.](http://www.sciops.esa.int/index.php?project=PLANCK&page=Planck_Published_Papers)  [The 'cosmological parameters' paper is the most relevant](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2013arXiv1303.5076P).

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar plot on page 41 (fig 25) of [Planck 2013 results. XVI. Cosmological parameters](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.5076v1), although it doesn't display supernova data.